# Abbreviation or complete names?

Tags: java, coding-style, naming-conventions

It is recommended that type names and virable names should avoid using abbreviations. It is also recommanded the source line width should be 80 or at most 120 characters even if modern wide screen monitors are used.

Here is a line from our real prject:

```
final PimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader pimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader = 
      new PimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader(pimAuthoringApplicationMappingFile);
```

A simple new operation occupied at least 2 lines, even though we have used an abbreviation here already (Pim = ProIntralink Merge).

Although it is easy to understand each words in this way, it makes a simple method much longer, and therefore difficult to fit one method in screen.

Question: what is the better way to deal with this case? Is "reasonable" abbreviation recommended - for example:

```
 final PimAuthAppMapReader pimAuthAppMapReader=new PimAuthAppMapReader(pimAuthAppMapFile);
```

?

Comment: I use a proportional font in my IDE so I get about 180 characters across the screen. At this point I wrap the code. However the Java Code Convention suggests 80 characters and I wouldn't expect this suggestion to change even if most developers perhaps don't follow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a familiar problem, the Java project I'm working on has some classes that make me scratch my head for the same reason. I shorten the local variable names before shortening the class names, but I have no problem shortening class names if the result is reasonable.

Breaking the convention of making the local variable the same name as its type frees up quite a bit of space in these cases. If more space is needed, I might shorten the type names as well.

In your example, I'm fine with shortening Application to App, but not so sure about shortening Mapping to Map because "map" has a different primary meaning (first association) in Java.

Answer (score 2):

I have always found strange the idea of naming variable with the same name as the implemented class (or interface). Same for shortened names.

It gives no information about the real purpose of the object in the context of its declaration, and it often get worse when you have multiple ones and star using numbers as suffixes.

So, instead, use a name that describes what is the intent of the object in the context, it will be easier when reviewing your code several months later.

Comment: This makes sense when your variable has a purpose/intent that can be used to describe it, for instance.     String string = user.getName(); doesn't make sense and would be better as    String userName = user.getUserName();  However, when you have a variable that is referring to a Class with a class name that describes what you are using the variable for, like:    User user = new User();  It makes sense to have the variable have the same name as the class.

Answer (score 2):

Above all, code must strive for *clarity*. Generally, this means *not* abbreviating, however in certain case s common abbreviations *improve* clarity. Often acronyms are not spelled out, but try to treat the acronym as a *word*, rather than keep the 'all caps' acronym.
Here are example of what I'm talking about:

```
HtmlRequest (not HTMLRequest)
App instead of Application
XmlProcessr instead of XMLProcessor
etc
```

Don't worry about page width. Worry about readability!

Comment: Page width cannot be changed as you wish, otherwise it will cause trouble when comparing different versions to find changes on CVS.

Answer (score 2):

I would keep the Class name verbose and shorten your variable names to something more sensible. Looking at your example I think this is a resonable effort:

```
final PimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader pimMappingReader = 
      new PimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader(pimMappingFile);
```

Keep in mind that the person reading your code is able to refer to the Type of a variable easily when you

1. Define your Classes for a specific purpose
2. Keep your methods brief
3. Declare your variables where they are used

My above example makes sense if there are not other Types being defined with very similar names. You could even argue that this also still makes sense if there's not much else going on in the same method and the variables a locally scoped

```
final PimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader pimReader = 
      new PimAuthoringApplicationMappingReader(pimFile);
```

I wouldn't shorten the Class names because you may be reading them without any context (e.g API docs, configuration files, etc)

But most of all try to code consistently. If a style has already been used, follow it unless you get everyone to agree to change it.